# Animating Orientation Switch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I created a simple video player that when portrait it shows the video in a small window on top of the view but when switched to landscape it automatically switches to full screen.

A lot like the youTube app does.

My issue is that it doesn't transition well to the full screen mode.  The navigation/tabbar controllers transition but my video just basically pops from one to the other.

Here's a little video of what's happening:

http://screencast.com/t/jaOoPOHLh

Here's the code I'm using to play the video and switch the orientation.

```
self.controller = [[LBYouTubePlayerController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fTIhC1WSew&list=FLEYfH4kbq85W_CiOTuSjf8w&feature=mh_lolz"] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
    self.controller.delegate = self;
    self.controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 180.0f);




- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    //self.controller.view.hidden = YES;

    UIDevice * device = note.object;


    switch(device.orientation)
    {

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            /* start special animation */
            self.controller.fullscreen = NO;
            //self.controller.view.hidden = NO;
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            /* start special animation */
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            // do something
            //self.controller.fullscreen = YES;
            //self.controller.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
            //self.controller.view.hidden = NO;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.controller.fullscreen = YES;
            self.controller.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
            self.controller.view.hidden = NO;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    };
}
```

Is there something I need to add or custom transition I'm suppose to do to make the video transition and match the navigation/tabbar?